# Proper syntax to pass multiple arguments to a method in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to remove all punctuation AND digits from a string using the method str.maketrans(). I've succeeded with two lines:

```
a_string = a_string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
a_string = a_string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.digits))
```

I'm curious if this can be done with a single line. The documentation for Python 3 states appropriate syntax is:

```
 str.maketrans( x [, y [, z] ] )
```

Is there a recommended syntax to incorporate multiple arguments for 'z'?

Comment: Woah, thank you @vaultah! I didn't realize you could combine with a '+'.

Comment: You could also simply chain the `.translate()` calls, because the first `.translate()` call returns a string, and strings have `.translate()` methods. But concatenating the strings in the call to `maketrans()` is more efficient.

Comment: I will research this option as well - thank you, @kindall.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, using '+' was the solution:

```
a_string = a_string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation + string.digits))
```